# Can you still program in xcode 7 with swift 2?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, project

Im working on a school project to build an iOS application in Swift. I saw that they updated to Swift 3.0 and now many tutorials don't work. My question is can you download xCode 7.3.1 and still work in Swift 2? So that I can follow the tutorials on the web?

My application only has to work on a emulator. So not in de App store

Thanks!

Comment: Xcode 7.x works with Swift 2.x.

Comment: I have xCode 8 on my mac but if I download 7.3.1 and delete the xCode 8 I can program in Swift 2.0? And follow the tutorials on the internet?

Comment: You can select legacy swift mode for your project and use Swift 2.3. This should be close enough for most tutorials

Comment: Always use latest version of Xcode and Swift version. Don't look back.

Comment: Use Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8. Avoid using old Xcode versions as much as possible.

Comment: Xcode 8 also can use Swift 2.3, Xcode 7 is just for it's extension now...

Comment: Xcode 8.2 (in Beta) will be the last version to support Swift 2.3. Anything done in Swift 2.x has a very short lifetime. Keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use swift 2.2 in Xcode 7 and 2.3 in Xcode 8 by enabling the Use `Legacy Swift Language` Version in `Build setting` (SWIFT_VERSION = 2.2)

Swift 2.2.1 and Swift 2.3 are very similar, with key changes being related to SDK differences.